# Sitecore Experience Profile taking long time to update visitors

Tags: experience-profile, goals

I'm trying to check the goals that were triggered by an anonymous visitor and other information in Sitecore Experience Profile. After I make my visit, when I check the Experience Profile, the new visit is not updated but it takes a lot of time to update. I'm only working on making new visits each time in Incognito mode.

I have enabled `IndexAnonymousContactData` setting to `true`. On each new visit I close the browser as well. Why I'm not able to see the new visits quickly or atleast in few minutes? What else should I do?

It will be much helpful if anybody can let me know whether it is possible to see the updates in Experience Profile in short time.

I'm using a fresh vanilla Sitecore instance. Sitecore version 9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting Sitecore documentation:

> **How recent is the data displayed in the Experience Profile?**

> The current contact session must have ended before data can be written to the MongoDB collection database. The default session timeout setting is 20 minutes. Therefore, data from the collection database populates the Experience Profile, at minimum, 20 minutes after the last session has ended.

> You can change the default setting if you want data to reach the collection database more quickly. To find the session timeout setting, open the web.config file from your website root folder and navigate to the  node and change the timeout setting to a lower value (in minutes):

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>
```

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/experience-profile-architecture-and-data-overview.html

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, I'll check this and update you.

Comment: This works fine. A lot better now. Thanks, it is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blog on how to end the user session, should speed things up a bit:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/154801/How-to-end-user-session-when-browser-closed-3

Essentially:

First create a page LogOut.aspx and in Page_Load event, write this code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
  Session.Abandon();
}
```