# Where can we set timestamp for experience analytic tracking records?

Tags: experience-analytics

We are using Experience Analytics for tracking the user activity records. However, it takes time for tracking so we would like to update its timestamp so we can get records as soon as possible but we have not found from where we can change the time interval.

We are using Sitecore 9.1.1 version using SXA.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link - https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/experience-profile-architecture-and-data-overview.html#how-recent-is-the-data-displayed-in-the-experience-profile

> The current contact session must have ended before data can be written
> to the collection database. The default session timeout setting is
> **20 minutes**. Therefore, data from the collection database populates the Experience Profile, at minimum, 20 minutes after the last session
> has ended.
>
> You can change the default setting if you want data to reach the
> collection database more quickly. To find the session timeout setting,
> open the web.config file from your website root folder and navigate to
> the node and change the timeout setting to a lower value (in minutes):
>
> ```
> <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>
> ```

I've tried this in Sitecore 9 instances, it works as expected.

**Credits :** https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/25819/4515

Comment: I have tried it and it does not show data with custom value for Experience Analytics