# Goals data not available in Experience Profile

Tags: goals

Using `Sitecore 10.1.2` on PaaS.

All the custom Goals are published and they are associated with respective page items.
I have browsed those pages, closed the browser.

There is no data available here.

[image]

This is our UAT environment. But I can see the data in the DEV environment.

Is there any configuration setting that I should check to fix this.

Comment: did you deploy marketing definitions ? https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/103/sitecore-experience-platform/deploy-marketing-definitions-and-taxonomies.html

Comment: Make sure you are browsing on CD or standalone instance.

Answer (score 2):

There may be many reasons for this, please verify the below points if there is no data present on the Sitecore experience profile dashboard.

1. Make sure the xConnect Service is running.
2. Make sure to Enable the indexing of anonymous contacts in the xDB index. ([refer](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/sitecore-experience-platform/enable-indexing-of-anonymous-contacts-in-the-xdb-index.html))
3. Make sure you have published the goals and also other pages where you associated the goals.

To validate Experience Profile just wait for 10-15 minutes or close the Session ([see this guide for how to speed up the Session spoofing and close cycles](https://sitecore.marcelgruber.ca/posts/xconnect-rapid-interaction-spoofing-contact-identification)).

You can lower the default session timeout to 1 minute as given [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/25818/sitecore-experience-profile-taking-long-time-to-update-visitors/25819#25819) then the visit to a page (that has a goal associated with it) in incognito mode, close the browser window.

After 1 minute, if everything works fine then it should populate that data in Experience Analytics and also in Experience Profile.

Hope it hepls!